# C program always uses 1503657284 or -1863345812 as entered scanf choice

Tags: c

I am learning C programming. In the following program I have 6 choices. User makes one of the 6 choices and the program prints some information. This goes on until the user says to quit. When I execute the program the `choice` is always 1503657284 but program exits fine when I press 6. I am using Eclipse on Fedora.

The code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int choice = 0;
    printf("Welcome to the program\n");

    while(choice != 6) {
        printf( "1. CHOICE 1\n"
                "2. CHOICE 2\n"
                "3. CHOICE 3\n"
                "4. CHOICE 4\n"
                "5. CHOICE 5\n"
                "6. Quit\n"
                "Please enter your choice: \n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("You made %d as your choice\n", &choice);
            switch(choice) {
                case '1' :
                    printf("CHOICE 1\n");
                    break;
                case '2' :
                    printf("CHOICE 2\n");
                    break;
                case '3' :
                    printf("CHOICE 3\n");
                    break;
                case '4' :
                    printf("CHOICE 4\n");
                    break;
                case '5' :
                    printf("CHOICE 5\n");
                    break;
                case '6' :
                    printf("CHOICE 6\n");
                    break;
                default :
                    printf("Choice not found\n");
                    break;
                }
    }
    printf("you have successfully made out");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run the program I get following.

```
Welcome to the program.
1. CHOICE 1
2. CHOICE 2
3. CHOICE 3
4. CHOICE 4
5. CHOICE 5
6. Quit
Please enter your choice: 
4
You made -1863345812 as your choice
Choice not found
1. CHOICE 1
2. CHOICE 2
3. CHOICE 3
4. CHOICE 4
5. CHOICE 5
6. Quit
Please enter your choice: 
2
You made -1863345812 as your choice
Choice not found
1. CHOICE 1
2. CHOICE 2
3. CHOICE 3
4. CHOICE 4
5. CHOICE 5
6. Quit
Please enter your choice: 
6
You made -1863345812 as your choice
Choice not found
you have successfully made out
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're printing the address of the `choice` variable. Your `printf` calls should just use `choice`, not `&choice`. Turn up (and/or pay attention to) your compiler warnings - it should have pointed this out.

Comment: You're using the address of the variable for the `printf`. Use: `printf("You made %d as your choice\n", choice);`

Comment: When you `scanf`, you must pass a pointer to integer, because the pointed-to memory should permanently change. When you `printf`, you just pass the `int` by reference. You have passed the address instead. Switch on your compiler warnings and you will be warned about format/argument mismatches.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Beat me by 11 seconds :)

Comment: `int choice` -> `case: '1'` - doubtful.

Comment: Thanks all that solves that mistake I overlooked.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Can switch statement use integer? You care right. all choices are being ignored. It defaults to the default choice.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thank you all. That solved both of my problems.

Comment: +1 for writing code that had a range check and printed "Choice not found\n".

Comment: @chux I hope that is a complement. I wouldn't understand sarcasm unless you say `Bazinga!!!` with it.

Comment: @donniezazen Yes: a complement.  All too often, code does not validate data and yours did.  Made your problem easier to solve.

Comment: this line: scanf("%d", &choice); has a few problems: 1) the format string does not allow for consumption of white space (especially the newline) and therefore probably will fail after the first time.  2) when using the I/O function (like scanf) the returned value should always be checked to assure the operation was successful. I.E. if( 1 != scanf( " %d", &choice ) ) { // handle error }

Comment: this line: printf("You made %d as your choice\n", &choice)  is printing the address of choice as an integer (results in undefined behaviour)  What you really want to do is print the contents of choice I.E. printf("You made %d as your choice\n", choice); note: no '&' on the parameter 'choice'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

First as said you are printing the memory address of the variable *choice* and not *choice* itself.So for that change your printf statement to:

```
printf("You made %d as your choice\n", choice);
```

Secondly , you make a switch with the wrong cases: You have to use the type you want to match , in this case the **int choice** , and **not a char**. So change your cases to be numbers and not characters:

```
case 1 : ...
```

instead of

```
case '1' :...
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is call by value, not call by reference.

```
printf("You made %d as your choice\n", choice);
```